# Google Charts - Custom Tooltip on Line Chart (Line Package) not Working

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I'm using Google Charts (Visualization, 1.1, Line Package) to create a Simple Chart with 3 Lines and Month and Costs Axis. Everything works fine, except Tooltip customization:

Here's my code

```
google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['line']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'Month');
  data.addColumn('number', "Line 1");
  data.addColumn('number', "Line 2");
  data.addColumn('number', "Line 3");
  data.addColumn({'type': 'string', 'role': 'tooltip', 'p': {'html': true}});

  data.addRows([
    [new Date(2015, 5),  1000,  980, 800, 'Custom Content 1'],
    [new Date(2015, 6),  1100,  1000, 970, 'Custom Content 2'],
    [new Date(2015, 7),  1550,  1420, 1200, 'Custom Content 3'],
    [new Date(2015, 8),  1050,  1200, 930, 'Custom Content 4'],
    [new Date(2015, 9),  1280,  1120, 1070, 'Custom Content 5'],
    [new Date(2015, 10),  1100,  999, 880, 'Custom Content 6'],

  ]);

  var options = {
    chart: {
      title: 'Custom ToolTips',
      subtitle: 'not working!'
    },
    focusTarget: 'category',
    tooltip: {isHtml: true},
    width: 900,
    height: 500 
  };

  var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('linechart_material'));
  chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));
}
```

You can test on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r2130cer/)

When you Hover the first bottom line you'll get:
[image]

But I Want to remove the Date on Top and Calculate Total Cost (Value * 2):
[image]

This is possible?

I already tried everything I could, search on Internet and try other codes but it looks like this isn't possible using th Line Package (Instead of CoreChart Package), is that right?

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: I dunno if you can remove the date (not sure) but you can add your total cost by just putting that data in the tooltip column. I'd be the first to agree that google charts tooltip is a nightmare to edit.

Comment: I can format the date on hAxis options but i can't remove this field on Tooltip... I still can't add Total Cost on Tooltip, even using string column and isHtml true option... @LiranBo

Comment: I tried but didn't succeed either. Next project I'll go back to AmCharts..

Answer (score 1):

copied from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29148517/4966682

After looking deeper into Google's Material Chart information I found on their website:

> The Material Charts are in beta. The appearance and interactivity are
>   largely final, but the way options are declared is not.

Trendlines and tooltips fall under the options section of creating charts since they need the options structure to further define them. Again, as of this date (March 2015) the Google Materials Charts do not support these features. If you want to use things like trendlines and tooltips you need to use non material charts (e.g. packages['corechart'] and not packages['scatter']).

Comment: Thanks for your reponse, I also read that documentation, that's where I took the chart draw information (google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options)). I also read that you can use "theme:material" on corechart package but I wonder if is possible to "hack" the default tooltip, just like I did on Legends. Thanks again.